# My Raspberry Pi 4 model B will not drive a Dell 1280 X 1024 60 Hz display

Tags: pi-4, display

Dell E170Sc 1280 X 1024 60 Hz vga displays are available for cheap on Ebay. I accept that (besides using hardware adapters) I will have to modify a config file to get my RPi to drive the display properly. My problem is that, in the boot directory, there are 11 config files: config-5.4.0-26-generic, config- 5.4.0-48-generic, config-5.4.0-51-generic, config-5.4.0-58-generic, config-5.4.0-59-generic, config-5.4.0-67-generic, config-5.4.0-74-generic, config=5.4.0-80-generic, config-5.4.0-81-generic, config-5.4.0-84-generic, and config-5.4.0-86-generic. Which config file do I edit to fix my no video problem?

Also, is this a good [site](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-screen-resolution/) for adjusting the video settings?

Comment: Where did these 11 config files come from?  My boot directory does not contain them.

Comment: This is also what I would like to know. I got the Rpi as a Canakit.

Answer (score 1):

> I will have to modify a config file to get my RPi to drive the display properly

Possibly; if so it *should* be `/boot/config.txt`, but it sounds like you have a bunch of `config`s there with kernel version tags associated with them.

I'm guessing these are *not* just variations of `config.txt` proper, since the latter doesn't actually have much to do with the kernel. It's used by the firmware to do various things before the kernel loads, although this includes creating a device tree for the kernel, which would be somewhat version dependent.

The `config.txt` we are interested in starts usually starts with a comment like this:

```
# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details
```

And consists of a short list (50 or so lines) of lower case option assignments like `gpu_mem=16`, most of which are commented out (`#`).

A linux kernel config is much longer and the options consist of all upper case letters.

Most likely, `config.txt` is just there amongst all the ones with the `-5.4.0` etc. suffixes.  The catch all option for screen troubles is the enable `#hdmi_safe=1` by removing the leading `#`.

The official documentation for configuring the display is here: https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#hdmi-configuration

Note that historically there have been issues with VGA adapters connected to the Pi, so YMMV there.

Comment: All of the config files use caps and all files end with "# end of Kernel hacking". None of them feature text anything like "gpu_mem=16". There is identical "graphics support" in all config files:
CONFIG_AGP=y
CONFIG_AGP_AMD64=y
CONFIG_AGP_INTEL=y
CONFIG_AGP_SIS=m
CONFIG_AGP_VIA=y
CONFIG_INTEL_GTT=y
CONFIG_VGA_ARB=y
CONFIG_VGA_ARB_MAX_GPUS=16
CONFIG_VGA_SWITCHEROO=y
CONFIG_DRM=m
CONFIG_DRM_MIPI_DBI=m
CONFIG_DRM_MIPI_DSI=y
CONFIG_DRM_DP_AUX_CHARDEV=y
and so on...

Comment: I am tempted to just blow it all way and install a new OS. I had trouble with the Raspberry Pi imager, though. When I clicked on "choose storage" it hung up - black screen.

Comment: Yeah, those are kernel configs.  They are used when building one, but sometimes get put alongside the compiled kernel for reference or re-use.  This is not a conventional practice with Raspbian/RpiOS, however.

Comment: How are you looking at these files? Might be worth noting that people using MS Windows systems occasionally get confused because the second (and largest partition) in the image/on the card is not readable on such systems without additional software, and may not be shown as existing at all.  The boot partition, though, is small, vfat formatted and only has one or two directories.  You might want to edit into the question the complete contents of the directory in which you found those files, that might help clarify what's going on.

Comment: "How are you looking at these files?" That is a good question, @goldilocks. I did format the SD card with the intention of installing a working OS. My problem at the moment is that my 64-bit Linux Mint 21 system will not mount an empty "mass storage device", so I am struggling with loading a fresh OS.

Comment: I was able to access that faulty SD card after I got a new SD card reader from Amazon. Then i was finally able to see files on that card, then flash a fresh OS. Thanks for all suggestions above.